# reduce nested dictionary of depth 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, foreach

I have a data structure:

```
 {"nodes": [
        {
            "NLPTag": {
                "value": "Pope",
                "pos": "PROPN",
                "index": 2,
                "uuid": "26acad7d-799b-4de2-9bfa-f0330aee4d79",
                "id": 816753
            }, .... ]}
```

which has a list of dictionaries. The key of this dictionary has the type. 
My desired output is:

```
 {"nodes": [
        {"type":"NLPTag",
         "value": "Pope",
         "pos": "PROPN",
         "index": 2,
         "uuid": 816753
            }, .... ]}
```

to do this I have tried:

```
data.nodes.map(function(node) {

        const type = Object.keys(node)[0];

        node[type]["type"] = type; 
        node[type]["id"] = node[type]["uuid"];
        delete node[type]["uuid"];

        return node[type] 

    })
```

but this results in a data structure with the similar nesting in example one. The dictionary at depth 2 has changed, but I have not removed the nesting:

```
data = {"nodes":[
          {"NLPTag": {
                "type":"NLPTag",
                "id":"26acad7d-799b-4de2-9bfa-f0330aee4d79"...
                     }
           },....]}
```

Can someone please help to tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructuring:

```js
const result = {nodes: data.nodes.map(item => ({...Object.values(item)[0] }))}
```

Demo:

```js
const data = {
    "nodes": [
        {
            "NLPTag": {
                "value": "Pope",
                "pos": "PROPN",
                "index": 2,
                "uuid": "26acad7d-799b-4de2-9bfa-f0330aee4d79",
                "id": 816753
            }, 
        },
        {
            "foo": {
                "value": "foo",
                "pos": "foo",
                "index": 2,
                "uuid": "foo",
                "id": 45654
            }, 
        }
    ]
}


const result = {nodes: data.nodes.map(item => ({...Object.values(item)[0] }))}

console.log(result);

// {
//     "nodes": [
//         {
//             "value": "Pope",
//             "pos": "PROPN",
//             "index": 2,
//             "uuid": "26acad7d-799b-4de2-9bfa-f0330aee4d79",
//             "id": 816753
//         },
//         {
//             "value": "foo",
//             "pos": "foo",
//             "index": 2,
//             "uuid": "foo",
//             "id": 45654
//         }
//     ]
// }
```